# Formatting text in widget textview

Tags: android, widget

I have a textview in my main app that I do some formatting on (breaks, resizing subset of the text, etc) using fromHtml() to create the string I use to populate the textview's text and I use the same code to populate the textview of my widget.  Unfortunately that code doesn't seem to work on the widget.  I can't get the font color, size, or style to change using fromHtml.  Is there a way to affect the style of a widget's textview in pieces (showing some text as a smaller part of the whole, or changing the font color, etc) or can I only affect the style of the whole textview by using the layout declaration of the textview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Styled text also does not work in widgets.
That may be the reason this failed.

No solution known yet. Only styles applied to the text-field as a whole working here.